# How to reshape data to new columns with a previous column value in sql bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I have a table with the following items and want to transform the table

| productID | Ourprice | source | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 25 | A | 20 |
| 2 | 25 | B | 30 |
| 2 | 25 | C | 40 |
| 2 | 25 | D | - |
| 5 | 20 | A | 30 |

into

| productID | Ourprice | APrice | BPrice | Cprice | Dprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 25 | 20 | 30 | 40 |  |
| 5 | 20 | 30 |  |  |  |

How to do this in sql bigquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *
from your_table
pivot (any_value(price) as price for source in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]